# I need a simple example of text rotation in canvas. No animation please

Tags: javascript, canvas, text, rotation

I need a simple example of text rotation in canvas. No animation please. I just want a simple static example.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a simple canvas text rotation example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/DominicCapuano/pen/Jjpzrwb). There is no animation as I am illustrating rotation only.

```
// This is a simple annotated example of text rotation in canvas.
// The x,y position of each example is  marked by a circle. This is the starting point of each sample text.
// Copyright Dominic Capuano 2022

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
drawGuideLines();   

ctx.font = "normal 36px Courier New";   

// No rotation applied.
ctx.strokeStyle="black";
ctx.fillText("SAMPLE TEXT no rotation",100,100);  
// Adding a character to the begining of the text will push the rest of the text to the right.  

// 0 degree rotation applied.   
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.save(); // Saves anything we have already drawn.
ctx.translate(100,200); // Sets a new (0,0) position on the canvas.
ctx.rotate(0 * Math.PI / 180);  // Rotate text 0 degrees. 
ctx.fillText("0 deg rotation SAMPLE TEXT",0,0);  // Position inside the new (0,0).
ctx.restore(); // Puts back our previously saved objects  and turns off rotation.
// Adding a character to the begining of the text will push the rest of the text to the right.      

// 90 degree rotation applied.  
ctx.fillStyle="blue";   
ctx.save(); // Saves anything we have already drawn.
ctx.translate(700,100); // Sets a new (0,0) position on the canvas.
ctx.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);  // Rotate text 90 degrees.
ctx.fillText("90 deg rotation SAMPLE TEXT",0,0);   // Position inside the new (0,0).
ctx.restore();   // Puts back our previously saved objects and turns off rotation.
// Adding a character to the begining of the text will push the rest of the text down. Text is perpendicular. 


// 180 degree rotation applied. 
ctx.fillStyle="green";  
ctx.save(); // Saves anything we have already drawn.
ctx.translate(600,300); // Sets a new (0,0) position on the canvas.
ctx.rotate(180 * Math.PI / 180);  // Rotate text 180 degrees.
ctx.fillText("180 deg rotation SAMPLE TEXT",0,0);  // Position inside the new (0,0).
ctx.restore();  // Puts back our previously saved objects and turns off rotation.       
// Adding a character to the begining of the text will push the rest of the text to the left. Text is upside down.      

// 45 degree rotation applied.  
ctx.fillStyle="purple";         
ctx.save(); // Saves anything we have already drawn.
ctx.translate(100,400); // Sets a new (0,0) position on the canvas.
ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI / 180);  // Rotate text 45 degrees.
ctx.fillText("45 deg rotation SAMPLE TEXT",0,0);  // Position inside the new (0,0)
ctx.restore();  // Puts back our previously saved objects and turns off rotation.
// Adding a character to the begining of the text will push the rest of the text downhill. Text appears to be going downhill.
```